# What type of dbwas used here

Tags: asp.net, database-connection

I'm moving website to new server. In archive file which I get I've got `.bak` file. Using `sqlcmd` I get `.mdf` and `.ldf` files. My question is what type of connection was used here and how should I add database to this project?

Below is file where is connection to db:

```
<%
' FileName="Connection_odbc_conn_dsn.htm"
' Type="ADO" 
' DesigntimeType="ADO"
' HTTP="true"
' Catalog=""
' Schema=""
Dim MM_xxx_STRING
MM_xxx_STRING = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Database=xxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;"
%>
```

Comment: Looks like Sql Server Express. You need to attach the mdf file to this kind of server.

Comment: How would look like connection if I uplaod database files? There should be file location or something but here was IP address only.

Comment: If the site and the database use the same server you can write ".\sqlexpress". If not, just replace the dot with the database server address. In default installation of sql express, the instance name is "sqlexpress", but you can install any version of sql server. If during installation you don't specify an instance name then you can remove the "\sqlexpress", or replace it with the instance name you specified.

Comment: And where should be db files on server? Also there is no filename in this connection. So everything stay as it is, the only thing I need to replace is IP address and put dot. And upload databace to root/public_html?

Comment: Install Sql Server Management Studio and use it to attach the mdf file. You should not be concerned where the server will put it. You don't have to copy the files to your site.

Answer (score 1):

It was a MS SQL Server (express edition).

I think in your target SQL server you can specify the .mdf file you want to use, when creating a new database.